# List the edges (vertex pairs) of a minimum spanning tree for this graph in the order they would be chosen by Prim's algorithm

Tags: algorithms, graphs

[image]

List the edges (vertex pairs) of a minimum spanning tree for this graph in the order they would be chosen by Prim's algorithm
Please help me to understand and complete this. I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?  We want to help you with your problems, not solve your exercise for you.  It's hard for us to know what you don't understand if you don't show us your thought process, what self-study you've done, what reasoning you've tried, and where you got stuck.  This is not an exercise outsourcing site where you can copy-paste your exercise and have us solve it for you.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a well-formed question; [Prim's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim's_algorithm) is dependent on which vertex you start with.  It is possible that other sources define the algorithm differently.

Let $V$ be the set of all vertices. The basic idea is:
Start with an arbitrary vertex, and add it to a new set $S$
Repeat the following until $S = V$:

- Find the lowest-cost edge $e$ that connects a $v \in S$ to a vertex
  $w \notin S$.
- Add that edge $e$ to a set of edges $T$ (it will become your tree).
- Add $w$ to $S$.

For example, suppose you started at vertex 4, so $S = \{4\}$ to start. The lowest-cost edge leading "out of" $S$ costs $2$, the edge connecting vertex 4 to 5. Now $S = \{4, 5\}$.

To get the full answer, you would continue this process until $S = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$. My issue with the problem is that the order the edges are chosen **depends on** the vertex you start with, but hopefully you are now more familiar with Prim's algorithm.

Comment: Please consider not to encourage [undesirable posting behaviour](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594).

Comment: Noted for the future. Unfortunately, I do not have enough reputation to comment on a question yet, so I thought I should give a short answer. Now I know better :)